# How to access one svg object using attribute "id" - javascript - D3

Tags: javascript, svg

If I give each svg object an id as follows:

```
var id = [0, 0, 0];
var links = svgCanvas.selectAll("line")
    .data(data.links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("id", function(thisData){
        if (thisData.node01 == "site01"){
            var position = id[0];
            var ids = position + 1
            id[0] = position + 1;
            return "A" + ids.toString();
        }
        if (thisData.node01 == "site02"){
            var position = id[1];
            id[0] = position + 1;
            return "B" + position + 1;
        }
        if (thisData.node01 == "site03"){
            var position = id[2];
            id[0] = position + 1;
            return "C" + position + 1;                
    })
```

So each line will have IDs A1-A10, B1-B10 and C1-C10.
How do I access a particular line to add modifications?

```
var pos;
if (site == "site01"){
    pos = "A";
}
if (site == "site02"){
    pos = "B";
}
if (site == "site03"){
    pos = "C";
}
var i;
for (i = 1; i< 11; i++){
    var po = pos + i.toString();
    console.log(po);
    svgCanvas.selectAll("line").select(["id" == pos]).attr("opacity", 1);
}
```

so basically, there is a .json file that has nodes and links. I want to be able to change the opacity of some of the lines that are connected to a particular node, when I hover over that node. If using the id is not a proper solution, is there any other way?